# Lock an Installation Folder, Even From Administrator?

Tags: windows-7, administrator, parental-controls, folder-lock

I have installed Norton Family parental control software on Windows 7. The issue is that people using the computer have figured out how to disable the program by manually deleting the installation folders off the hard drive.

I have used a program called "folder lock", but if the installation folder is locked Norton Family can't start up with the OS.

My Windows 7 installation has one account, and it has administrator privileges. I cannot change this due to some organizational reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make a limited user account in order for the parental controls to work properly. Windows requires at least 1 administrative user at all times, who can override almost anything. Therefore, permissions could be changed on programs.Once you create a limited user, it will be locked down enough.

Another alternative is to use open dns, but it is still able to be by passed, unless you are able to proxy everything through a physical connection before the internet, such as a router. Again, easy to bypass if you're an administrator.

Comment: So you're thinking that the only way to make a parental control work is to have an OS with multiple accounts of which one is administrator and one is limited user.

Comment: It's the only way to secure it, yes